# Must or had to?

Tags: grammar

"Now Skouri turned his thoughts to what lay ahead. He **must** make certain that everything went perfectly at the airport." 
(The Other Side of Midnight by Sidney Sheldon)

I keep telling myself that the author should have used "had to" which is the past of must, as I learned. So why must? could "must" also express the past tense?

Thank you.

Comment: It is the present tense from his point of view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible parsings of this *must*:

1. Although today *must* is **usually** expressed with *had to* in past tense, *must* may also act as its own past tense—historically, in fact, it was  the past-tense form of the now-defunct verb *mote*. Note that most of the modals employ past-tense forms with both past and present reference in some contexts; for example

   - John **says** we might/could/should/must file an objection.
   - John **said** we might/could/should/must file an objection.
2. Alternatively, you may understand *must* here as reflecting Skouri's actual thoughts at the time, as if the sentence were in quotes. This is a very common literary device.

Comment: Can *should* be used for the past tense of *must*, or is it a deprecated usage?

Comment: @ustanak No; *should* and *must* have slightly different meanings, depending on context. The syntax of modal verbs is complicated, but the semantics of modal verbs is **vastly** complicated: entire books have been written on the semantics, and they often disagree because the use of modal verbs changes constantly over time.

Comment: Thank you. I'd use *should* sometimes as the past tense of *should*. However, last time I saw a movie where a person said *I should go* and it was clear that in the scene meant the past.

Answer (score 1):

**Must** does express the past tense in reported speech [**here**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51023/is-must-ever-grammatical-as-a-past-tense-verb) and [**here**](http://www.171english.cn/html/grammar/00065.htm)

Comment: Thanks a lot to you all. I feel that I'll learn a great deal here.